# use same datasource from already started server

Tags: spring, hibernate, jms, jboss7.x, datasource

I have configured jBoss 7.1.1 final for datasource and used it in spring by JNDI. Everything is working fine , datasource is up and JMS queue is setup. Now I have to run a batch which will fetch records from DB and put it in JMS(already started instance) . I have to use same datasource which is configured in server but the record fetching program is a normal java program and I am using same configuration as defined in my spring-servlet.xml

```
    <bean id="TransactionalDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/FRMWRKPOC_DEV"></property> 
    </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="TransactionalDataSource"/>
     <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>entities</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
  </bean>
```

The java code to get sessionFactory is as follows:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
                SessionFactory factory  = (SessionFactory)context.getBean("sessionFactory"); 
                return factory;
```

But it is giving me following error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

If some kind of initial context setup is required then please guide me and also tell me is it possible to get the datasource instance if the application is not running on server though server is already started(because it is normal PSVM java code)

Please find below the complete stacktrace

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NonTransactionalDataSource' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.rights.client.DBConnection.getSessionFactory(DBConnection.java:33)
    at com.rights.client.SwonToSubLocMapping.main(SwonToSubLocMapping.java:146)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: post complete stacktrace of the error to your question

Answer (score 0):

As you are using it as a normal Java program, you have to provide details to `Spring` on how to access the `JNDI` by providing required properties. For `JBOSS` you can declare it like this:

```
<bean id="TransactionalDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/FRMWRKPOC_DEV"></property>
   <property name="jndiEnvironment">
      <props>
         <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
      <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">localhost:1099</prop>
      <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
      <props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: @Chaitnya I am using jBoss 7.1.1 so I have used these details

Comment: I am using jBoss 7.1.1 so used these details
 <props>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://localhost:4447</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>

but now I am getting 
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed

I have added application user in my jBoss server but i dont know how to provide these details in xml. kindly help me out.

Comment: now I am able to provide the credentials and got the remote connection but now getting this error 
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/FRMWRKPOC_DEV -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.comp.env.jdbc.FRMWRKPOC_DEV

help me out..

Comment: @rishi, please update your question with what modifications you have done and also add the complete stacktrace of the error you are facing now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write simple java program or jsp to read from JNDI. It looks like you need to pass authentication (principal & credential) and authorization (I think its optional) inforamtion while conncting to JNDI.